# PHP_LDAP: Test that Organizational Unit exist?

Tags: php, ldap

I was wondering if anyone knew of a good way to determine if a specific OU exists by providing the DN of the OU using the LDAP extension for PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing around with the ldap_search function for a while, I figured out a fairly reliable way. This worked well with Active Directory, I am not sure if this will work with OpenLDAP.

```
/**
 * @param $ldap
 * @param $search_base
 * @param $dn
 * @return bool
 */
public function test_ou($ldap, $search_base, $dn)
{
    $filter = '(&(objectClass=top)(|(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(objectClass=container))(distinguishedName=' . $dn . '))';
    $results = ldap_get_entries($ldap, ldap_search($ldap, $search_base, $filter, array('objectGUID')));
    return ($results['count'] > 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it late but maybe it can help someone in future 
i create dn_exists like file_exists (return true or false ) it take an OU in parametre for exemple OU=Utilisateus,DC=company,DC=dz, good luck :)

```
public function dn_exists($dn){
    $filter="(&(ObjectClass=person))";
    //$this->ldap_resource_link connection to LDAP
    $read = @ldap_search($this->ldap_resource_link, $dn, $filter,array('ou'));
    return $read;

}
```

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted answer, because it 'tests that an Organizational Unit exists', where the accepted answer tests if there are entries inside an Organizational Unit, which could return false, while the OU is actually present. It is only missing a conversion of the result into a boolean return value.